# Vectorizing in MATLAB to avoid for loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the following code snippet which is using two for loops for N^2 iterations. How can I do this? (Just to know the flow, This code is used to resample the given samples and weights such that the ouput has new sample sets which is formed based on the weights and after resampling weight of each sample is distributed uniformly)

```
function [Xr, Wr, j] = resampl(X, W)
%RESAMPLE Resample particles and output new particles and weights.
% resampled particles. 
%
%   if old particle vector is x, new particles x_new is computed as   x(:,j)
%
% Input:
%   X   [n x N] Particles, each column is a particle.
%   W   [1 x N] Weights, corresponding to the samples
%
% Output:
%   Xr  [n x N] Resampled particles, each corresponding to some particle 
%               from old weights.
%   Wr  [1 x N] New weights for the resampled particles.
%   j   [1 x N] vector of indices refering to vector of old particles

% Your code here!
N = size(X,2);
Wt = sum(W);

Wr = ones(1,N)/N;

for i = 1:N
  B = Wt*unifrnd(0,1);
  for ip = 1:N
    B = B - W(ip);
    if B < 0
       j(i) = ip;
       break;
    end
  end
end

for i = 1:N
    Xr(:,i) = X(:,j(i));
end
end
```

Comment: You don’t preallocate `j` or `Xr`. That should significantly speed up your code.

Comment: Hello Cris, Could you please elaborate? I need to run this function for 1000 times. That would take 1000*N*N iterations. In the previous comment I guess you are asking me to preallocate j and Xr. That is helpful.. Thank you. But how can I vectorize this code or atleast use only one for loop.

Comment: [MATLAB documentation on preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)

Comment: You don't seem to be needing j, you could just put `Xr(:,i) = X(:,ip);` inside the `if B<0`. You could also do initialization of Wr in two steps to avoid division. `Wr = ones(1,N); Wr(:) =1/N;`. Apart from preallocating j and Xr though as Cris suggested or getting rid of j if you don't need it and the very minor improving of setting the values instead of performing division, your code is pretty much vectorized.